# blood fluidics - can you determine the force exerted on a bound red blood cell under shear stress?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Is it possible to calculate the force exerted on a bound, infected red blood cell under various shear stresses? The strength of an adhesive interaction is normally measured by SPR or AFM, however using microfluidics, you can increase the shear stress until the cell dislodges, therefore, can you use this data to calculate force?

Comment: SPR and AFM might not be common abbreviations to everybody.

Comment: SPR - surface plasmon resonance and AFM - Atomic force microscopy. These methods normally measure the strength of binding between a purified receptor and ligand pair. However these methods are not representative of the interaction in vivo. That's why I am trying to find out if it's possible to determine the force needed to dislodge my parasites from my flow assays.